# Parellel.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing

I am trying to use Parallel.js (http://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/) in my code
In the html page the parallel.js script then in my code I placed these lines

```
parallelStarts = true;
var parallel = new Parallel(this.chromosomes, {
  maxWorkers: 4,
  evalPath: 'js/eval.js',
  env: {
    state: pslg.state,
    totalDiffLevels: pslg.LevelGenerator.levelsOutline.length
  }
});

parallel.map(function(chromosome) {
  chromosome.CalculateFitness(global.env.state, global.env.totalDiffLevels);
  return chromosome;
}).then(function(res) {
  parallelStarts = false;
}, function(res) {
  console.logError("Parallelism Failed");
});

while (parallelStarts) {}
```

I tried everything and nothing happens the function is not called by anything because it never change the parallelStarts variable to false.

Any help?

Comment: That infinite loop will block anything else from happening. Don't do that.

Comment: yeah its infinite loop but I break from it by finishing the parallel processing :)

Comment: Except it doesn't work, right? OK I think I see what you're trying to do; do you have any indication that your worker code is running at all?

Comment: yes but how can I wait till all workers finish :) I looked at the example on the website for the Fiboni series and it do the same I do but works

Comment: http://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/js/main.js

Comment: Are you running this in Node or in a browser?

Comment: in browser from the debugging of Netbeans

Comment: It seems the `.then` callback is in the same thread as the infinite loop, that will make it impossible to run due to the infinite loop.

Comment: I will check that and see :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like that infinite loop block all.

I suggest that use [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) or [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to check if `parallelStarts` variable changed his value, instead of infinite loop.

Comment: Okay will check that but why my code is not doing the same I just blocked the code till finish instead of making multifunctions?

Comment: Not the same, it's impossible to run `.then` until infinite loop finish. I think like @qantas-94-heavy about this.

Comment: Thanks I tried it on simple website and it was the problem but in my main code its not good with that  so is there a way to make it wait because I am trying to make genetic Algorithm and I am calculating the fitness function in parallel for each chromosome